# Blocking internet access on Web hosting server & SSL certificate validation

Tags: ssl, web-hosting, x509certificate, ca

We are working to block all outgoing internet access on our web-server. There are about 200 websites / applications hosted . We want to white list all out going traffic & block everything else.

There are some applications ( Web-services ) which use X509Certificate authentications.

Now question is , does X509 certificate authentication require internet access to validate certificate from CA / certificate revocation information ?

How do I know white list URL's for it ?